# How to backup / dump own chat / messages from Discord (DiscordApp), only from own user @alias

Tags: backup, api, dump, discord

I wonder how I could backup / dump my own messages from DiscordApp chats, conversations, general chat etc (user have `@alias`, or defined by `unique-id`, integer as id, etc) from DiscordApp, Discord.

Is there any tool, app or cli script for scrape (easily) Discord app API for own messages only? I didn't find too much info.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No need to resort to unofficial hacks; if I'm understanding your question correctly, this is actually a built-in feature of the Discord service:

From Discord support page "[Requesting a Copy of your Data](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004027692-Requesting-a-Copy-of-your-Data)":

> If you would like to request a copy of the personal data you've given us over the lifetime of your account, you can do so by going to **User Settings** -> **Privacy and Safety and clicking the "Request all of my Data" button. This button exists everywhere you can use Discord (Desktop App, Browser, and on Mobile!).

According to [another support page](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004957991-Your-Discord-Data-Package), this data includes, among other things:

> **Your Messages:** All messages you have sent in servers, DMs or group DMs, unless it has been deleted manually by you or someone else. This folder will also include links to attachments uploaded.

This sounds like exactly what you're looking for. That said, for anyone who needs a full chat log, OP's own solution of using DiscordChatExplorer would likely be a better bet.